# Parsing a WHERE clause string in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am using Java version 1.7
I have a String:

```
String customerList="'C1','C2','C3','C4','C5'";
```

I would like to parse each customer into individual Strings, like

String C1, C2, C3, C4 and C5

How do I do this?

Comment: String [] customers = customerList.splitString(",");

Comment: `split()` and `replace()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

```
String customerList="'C1','C2','C3','C4','C5'";
for( String s : customerList.split(",") ) {
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("'", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String customerList="'C1','C2','C3','C4','C5'";    

String[] a = customerList.replace("'", "").split(",");
```

Now `a` holds `Strings` `"C1", "C2"` etc...

Testing with:

```
for(String x : a)
    System.out.print(x + " ");
```

will print `C1 C2 C3 C4 C5`